# How to query for loop every 7 days and group by name

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, laravel, group-by

I want to query data in `member` table. 
What's sql query? or eloquent for laravel framework ?

**Condition**

1. query loop every 7 days, start Wednesday 00:00 AM and end Tuesday 11:59 PM
2. group by member each loop and sum price

**tbl_member**

```
id | member| price | datetime
1  | AAAAA | 100   | 2015-08-01 00:00:00 
2  | BBBBB | 100   | 2015-08-02 00:00:00 
3  | BBBBB | 100   | 2015-08-03 00:00:00 
4  | CCCCC | 100   | 2015-08-10 00:00:00 
5  | AAAAA | 100   | 2015-08-11 00:00:00 
6  | BBBBB | 100   | 2015-08-15 00:00:00 
7  | CCCCC | 100   | 2015-08-20 00:00:00 
8  | AAAAA | 100   | 2015-08-22 00:00:00 
9  | AAAAA | 100   | 2015-08-25 00:00:00
```

**For example**

```
(29-04/08/2015)
  1 | AAAAA | 100 | 2015-08-01 00:00:00 
  2 | BBBBB | 200 | 2015-08-02 00:00:00 (group by member id:2, id:3)

(05-11/08/2015)
  4 | CCCCC | 100 | 2015-08-10 00:00:00  
  5 | AAAAA | 100 | 2015-08-11 00:00:00

(12-18/08/2015)
  6 | BBBBB | 100 | 2015-08-15 00:00:00

(19-25/08/2015)
  7 | CCCCC | 100 | 2015-08-20 00:00:00
  8 | AAAAA | 200 | 2015-08-22 00:00:00 (group by member id:8, id:9)
```

Comment: "What's sql syntax???" u need a query or what?

Comment: Yes, I need a query. Can u help me?

Comment: your question alittle bit confusing. add more explanations what u want to recieve. More about "conditions"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the loop in php and query for each date range.
Here is the eloquent for grabbing the values.

```
Member::whereBetween('datetime', [$startDateTime, $endDateTime])
      ->groupBy('member')
      ->select('id', 'member', DB::raw('SUM(price) as price'), 'datetime')
      ->get();
```